# Simple math pattern--does it work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

So a friend of mine just pointed this out:

$$ \text {If} \ \; 0<a<b \; \text{then} $$
$$ b^3-a^3=(a^2+ab+b^2)(b-a) $$
$$ b^4-a^4=((a^3)+(a^2b)+(ab^2)+(b^3))(b-a) $$
$$ b^5-a^5=((a^4)+(a^3b)+(a^2b^2)+(ab^3)+(b^4))(b-a) $$

Does this scale for higher exponents and does it work for all real numbers?

Comment: It works on a number of levels. It works for all real numbers and not just that.

Comment: @GitGud Really? What else does it work for?

Comment: @Noob It works on any commutative ring. In particular it works for fields, for example $\mathbb C$. The kind of examples I can give depend on the mathematics you know. It's hard for me to exemplify without knowing what you know.

Comment: @GitGud Feel free to just explain it, I'm more interested in learning something new than applying something I already know. Also, for the benefit of other viewers to the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have by simple change of index:

$$(a-b)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-1-k}b^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-k}b^k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-1-k}b^{k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-k}b^k-\sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{n-k}b^{k}=a^n-b^n$$
so your pattern works *(and it's a classic result)*.

Answer (score 0):

Another pattern that may interest you is

$$(b+a)(b-a) = b^2 - a^2$$
$$(b+a)(b^2-ab+a^2) = b^3 + a^3$$
$$(b+a)(b^3-ab^2+a^2b-a^3) = b^4 - a^4$$
$$(b+a)(b^4-ab^3+a^2b^2-a^3b+a^4) = b^5 + a^5$$
$$\dots$$